# ElasticSearch/Lucene - Apply slop to NOT

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I have a field in ElasticSearch that is an array of strings.

I'm searching for specific phrases in that array using [position increment gap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/position-increment-gap.html) and [phrase_slop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

The initial matching works fine. However, I can't figure out how to negate by specific field values.

Examples:

Indexed field: `['a b 1', 'c d', 'e f 3']`

Basic phrase match:

- `"a c"` matches nothing (desired behavior)
- `"b a"` matches when `phrase_slop` is high enough (desired behavior).

Negating:

- `"a b" NOT 1 NOT 3` matches nothing (desired behavior)
- `**"a b NOT 1 NOT 3" matches nothing (NOT desired behavior)**

Is there any way that I can use a phrase match with phrase slop AND negate based on *position*?

*Current Solution*:

For my specific use case I think I found a workaround:

More details:

- There's a limited number of values that I need to `NOT` against.
- Unlike the question example, there's a fairly small number of array values that contain the `NOT` values.
- Sometimes I do not need to add the `NOT`s. However, those times should be clear from the user input.

So, my solution is to use 2 fields: One with array values that I wanted to `NOT` against and one without.

I'm still curious if there's an easier/more general solution without splitting to the two fields.

Comment: No, phrase queries don't really provide any sort of syntax like that within the phrase. To accomplish this, you would need to use span queries, which are essentially the building blocks of a phrase query.  You can read up on the [elasticsearch span query api here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html). It's not clear to me what you are expecting that query to do, so I won't attempt to provide an example.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks for the comment. I think span queries would have technically allowed me to keep using one field (which I didn't think was possible before). I'm going to go ahead and use the 2 field approach because it works for my specific use case. If you think it's possible to create an answer out of what you mentioned before I'll accept that answer.